# Dynamic text in pdf

Tags: php, codeigniter, tcpdf

I use pdf and I encountered the following problem:
When I write a text everything is ok but when I want to write a dynamic text like "Hello X" where X is taken from the database it doesn't work. I mean, I didn't show the name from the database.

I write it using the code below:

```
$ pdf-> Write (0, 'Faculty of Aerospace', '', 0, 'L', true, 0, false, false, 0);
$ paragraph. = '
<P>
I am writing this letter in support of <? Php if ($ sex == "male"):?> Mr. <? Php else:?> Ms. <? php endif?> <? php echo $ nume_student;?>, who is a Computer-aided graphics student at our college. </p> ';
$ pdf-> Write (0, $ paragraph, '', 0, 'J', true, 0, false, false, 0);
```

I want to appear I am writing this letter in support of Mr......
But actual appear

I am writing this letter in support of `<? Php if ($ sex == "male"):?> Mr.`

Comment: `$paragraph. = '<p>I am writing ...'. ($sex == "male") ? 'Mr.': 'Ms.' . 'continue...`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot use `<?php .... ?>` inside a PHP string.

```
$pdf->Write(0, 'Faculty of Aerospace', '', 0, 'L', true, 0, false, false, 0);

$paragraph = "<p>I am writing this letter in support of " .
             ($sex == "male" ? "Mr. " : "Ms. ") . $nume_student .
             " who is a Computer-aided graphics student at our college.</p>";

$pdf->Write(0, $paragraph, '', 0, 'J', true, 0, false, false, 0);
```

These are very basic syntax problems.